# Repeat Foreach limit

Tags: php, foreach, limits

I have this code

```
<?php foreach ($column as $k => $v): ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $k; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

And i get this output

```
<tr>
   <td>id</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>birth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>foto</td>
</tr>
```

but i don't want to include the foto, how can i do this ?

Comment: The output is showing only one `td` per row. are they keys or value?

Comment: Your output doesn't support your code. Please check

Comment: How do you want to omit `foto`? is it like the last element or is it like whenever you find the word `foto` you want to omit?

Comment: can you share the value of `$column`? do `echo "<pre/>";print_r($column);` before `foreach()` and show us the output (Add in your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use if condition inside foreach

```
<?php foreach ($column as $k => $v): 
    if($v=='foto'){ // skip iteration if value is `foto`
    continue;
    }
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $k; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following before starting the loop-

If `foto` is the **key** -

```
if(isset($column['foto']))
    unset($column['foto']);
```

If `foto` is **value** -

```
if(in_array('foto', $column))
    unset($column[array_search('foto', $column)]);
```

After that looping starts -

```
<?php foreach ($column as $k => $v): ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $k; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```